# Query a Julia dictionary for certain values

Tags: linq, julia

I am not new to programming but I am new to Julia. I have a Julia dictionary object that looks like the following:

```
Dict{Any,Any}(28.1=>1, 132.0=>2, 110.0=>3)
```

How can I write code to filter out the values that meet a certain criteria? Like let's say that I want all pairs where the value is >2 or >=2. I'm basically looking for the LINQ equivalent in Julia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Base`, the standard way is to use `map` and `filter`:

```
julia> d = Dict{Any,Any}(28.1=>1, 132.0=>2, 110.0=>3);
julia> filter((k, v) -> v > 2, d)
Dict{Any,Any} with 1 entry:
  110.0 => 3
```

If you use DataFrames, there is a LINQ-like interface in [DataFramesMeta](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFramesMeta.jl).

Comment: This is not working anymore (Julia 1.5). ```ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#72#73")(::Pair{Any,Any})```

Comment: Yes, now you need to do `filter(kv -> kv.second > 2, d)`.

Comment: Pairs destructure into two arguments, e.g., `k, v = first(iterate(d))` unpacks the first key-value pair of `d` into `k` and `v`. I wonder why pairs no longer get similarly unpacked into the arguments of `(k, v) -> v`?